Mercury in dam’s reservoirs
When a hydroelectric dam’s reservoir is flooded, organic matter which is now submerged in water starts decomposing. Mercury is produced and is harmful for the ecosystems and for humans. What would be the solution to avoid the production of mercury when building new dams or how could it be dealth with?

Mercury? or did you mean methane? BIG difference between the two and you need to understand that.

nothing "produces" mercury, mercury is an element

Things harmful to humans play a crucial role as negative feedback in the planetary ecosystem. One solution is to let nature take its course (it will do so regardless of any human actions anyway).
